# Can a property hold almost everywhere and also nowhere?

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let $X$ = {0}. Use the trivial measure on $X$ such that $\mu(A)$ = 0 for all measurable sets in $X$. Let the property $P$ be such that $P$ does not hold at 0. But then there exists a set $N = X$ with $\mu(N) = 0$ and all $x \in X - N = \emptyset$ have the property $P$ (this is true since there is no such $x$). Thus, it appears that $P$ holds almost everywhere on $X$. But, simultaneously, there is no $x \in X$ such that $P$ holds, so we might say $P$ holds nowhere.

Is then correct that a property can hold almost everywhere and also nowhere as in the above example, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Sure, but it only comes up in the uninteresting case of measure spaces that have total measure $0$. Integration on such spaces is completely trivial, which defeats most of the point of measure spaces.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't it the case that using a measure subspace that this could easily arise? E.g. if we have R^2 and use the Lebesgue measure and consider the subspace S = {x, y in R^2: x = 0} then that has measure zero everywhere so every property is vacuously true on S. Perhaps is there some better way to define measure subspaces than the usual one that causes this issue? I'm not super familiar with measure theory so I apologize if my questions are naive.

Comment: @ConnellyBarnes this is why one is not worried about what happens on measure zeros sets

Comment: It just seems to me that unless there is a better way to construct a subspace measure then the standard definition of subspace measure seems ill-equipped for characterizing properties being almost everywhere on subspaces of various dimension. I just wonder are there any other techniques people use to construct subspace measures if it is desired to characterize whether properties are almost everywhere in a way that doesn't give vacuous results?

Comment: You might want to look at Hausdorff measures.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I was wondering whether ideas similar to Hausdorff dimension could be used to construct a measure and it looks like that notion is well-developed.

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for similar concepts it seems Minkowski content and the disintegration theorem are also related.

Comment: To be **and** not to be, is that the question ?

Comment: @ConnellyBarnes: For that particular case, the natural fit is probaby something like Fubini's theorem to deal with nice subspaces, or even submanifolds and differential forms. There's also a troublesome problem in the opposite direction for measures that aren't complete, where subsets of measurable sets of measure $0$ may not even be measurable (cf. Lebesgue versus Borel measure).